# Best way to insert data from datatgridview into database without textbox and button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` and I want when edit a cell data directly insert into database. I don't want use textbox and button. how do I dothis?

Comment: `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` is another event which can be used for saving  changed data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using CellValueChanged event if you are using WindowsForms. Here's the reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tank you so much. is this the best way?

Comment: If you want to edit and save the object on the GridView controls cell value changed then yes.
if you aren't using MVVM pattern.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364485/MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel-Patte